# Issue with the width of a viewpager in Android

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, android-relativelayout

I am having a really weird problem. Here it goes:

I have got a viewpager which I use to navigate between some fragments. In one of those Fragments I am adding a surfaceview that is supposed to fill the whole UI to a relativelayout. I add it like this:

```
mRelativeLayout.addView(mMySurfaceView);
```

Now, the problem is that even though the surfaceview fills up the whole screen, the viewpager does not. There is a small gap between viewpager and screen border. In other words, the viewpager does not fill up the whole width.

However, when I add another ui element to my relativelayout, like an imagebutton like this:

```
mRelativeLayout.addView(myImageButton);
```

then everything is fine and the viewpager fills up the whole screen.

Why is this happening??

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
//in onMesure()
mMySurfaceView.setMeasuredDimension(int, int)
```

more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,int)